How to open a Diagnostic logs file from Azure DevOps?
After deploying the release to another environment, I encountered the following log:

Sorry, the app encountered a non-recoverable error and will need to terminate. The exception details have been captured and will be forwarded to the development team, if telemetry has been enabled.
The diagnostic logs can be found at: D:\file_path\bin\pac\tools\logs\log.txt"

Where should I look for it?

It will be very hard to help you with such a vague question - please edit your question and add more context/details.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
